# Why does my UILabel fail to show a successfully fetched value?

Tags: swift, uiview, google-cloud-firestore, uilabel

I have a UIView which displays a string fetched from my Firestore database.
While the code does fetch the string successfully and print it, it fails to show up in my UILabel, ie, my UIlabel shows the word "defaultValue".

My code is as follows:

```
var myString: String?

lazy var myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "\(myString ?? "defaultValue")"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame)

    let docRef = db.collection("collection").document("document")

    popUpListener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        guard let myStringg = document.get("field") else {
            return
        }

        self.myString = "\(myStringg)"
        print(myStringg)                 // Does indeed print out fetched value.
    }
```

Comment: I don’t see you adding the label to the view, setting the label's text, or frame/constraints. Need more information.